# Selecting data from csv

Tags: javascript, csv, jet

i want to select data from csv file here is my code

```
var filenamecsv="D://Data.csv";
adoConn1.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=d:\;
               Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited';");
adoRS1.Open("Select * From Data.csv",adoConn1,1,3);
```

but when i execute my project i get following error

> Microsoft JET Database Engine: The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the 
>           object 'Data.csv'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name 
>           and the path name correctly.

what should i do?

Comment: Like the error message is saying you should do: "Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly".

Comment: every thing is fine file exists and spell are correct i have checked and then post here

Comment: if the file actually exists at D:\, it could be that you need brackets around your table name, ie `[Data.csv]`

Comment: Does D> exists where the JavaScript is executed? Or just locally when you develop it? Can the browser see the external drive? Why open a file fro JS/browser like this anyway?

Comment: dear Baszz i told every thing is fine rights etc but this problem is just with csv format type of file is Microsoft Office Excel Comma Separated Values Filei am not getting the problem solution so posted here

Comment: System.IO.Path.GetFileName how can we write in javascript or what is its replace in javascript

Comment: It could be that you need to escape your `\ ` in `D:\ ` in the connection string and use `Data Source=D:\\;`

Comment: thats the right answer dear frnd thank u very much it worked.

Comment: @oracle certified professional It would be great if you could post your comment as an answer.

Comment: how to do that plz post your comment in answer so that i tick as asnwer thanks

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you need to escape your backslash in `D:\` in the connection string and use `Data Source=D:\\;`

Comment: i have no complete reputation to st it as answer dear frnd

Comment: no mind, but _everyone_ can set the answer to their own question. it's the tick underneath the voting down arrow on the answer (it should be just an outline). click that to turn it green.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `"D://Data.csv"`, try `"D:\data.csv"`.

See here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile for a useful reference.